# How to replace all linefeeds with "\n" in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to convert multiple lines content into a single line content by replacing all linefeeds in a variable with "`\n`" in bash.

**Here is the test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    local test_string="$(cat <<'END'
line1
    line2
line3
END
    )"
    
    test_string="${test_string/\n/\\n}"
    
    printf "%s" "$test_string"
}

hello
```

**Here is the output:**

```
li\ne1
    line2
line3
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
line1\n    line2\nline3
```

What's wrong in the above code and how to fix?

Comment: Replacing linefeeds with, err, linefeeds, won't accomplish anything.

Comment: @user207421 : I think the OP just worded the question sloppily. He wants to replace each line feed character by the two characters _backslash_ and _n_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your substitution expression:

```
test_string="${test_string/\n/\\n}"
```

First, you need `//` in order to replace all occurrences of the pattern in the variable:

```
test_string="${test_string//\n/\\n}"
```

(See the `Parameter Expansion` of the man page for more details on this syntax.)

And second, a regular bash string doesn't know anything about `\n`; that just means `n`, which is why you see the output you've shown. You need to use a `$'...'` expression, like this:

```
test_string="${test_string//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

(See the `QUOTING` section of the man page.)

With those changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    local test_string="$(cat <<'END'
line1
    line2
line3
END
    )"

    test_string="${test_string//$'\n'/\\n}"
 
    printf "%s" "$test_string"
}

hello
```

Your script produces:

```
line1\n    line2\nline3
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but rather than using `cat` and process substitution to set your variable, you could do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    local test_string
    read -r -d '' test_string <<'END'
line1
    line2
line3
END
    test_string="${test_string//$'\n'/\\n}"
    printf "%s\n" "$test_string"
}

hello
```

Comment: If you mean two backslashes where you wrote `//` you should correct your answer.

Comment: @user207421 I did not mean "two backslashes". The syntax presented here is correct and exactly what I meant. The `//` sequence is part of a bash substitution expression (as seen in `test_string="${test_string//\n/\\n}"`). See the [Shell Parameter Section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of the documentation for details.